# What improvements I can make on student attendance NoSQL database?

Tags: database, firebase, nosql

I’m designing a NoSQL database for student attendance system, I want your advices to improve it since I’m new to this field.

I want to query 1. classes for specific student,  2. students on specific class, 3. Attendees for specific class on specific date, 4. attendance and absence count for specific student on specific class.

```
{
  "attendance" : {
    "CS 331" : {
      "7-3-2019" : {
        "2014901001" : true
      }
    }
  },
  "class" : {
    "class01" : {
      "id" : "CS 331",
      "name" : "Software Design",
      "students" : {
        "2014901001" : true
      }
    }
  },
  "classEnrollment" : {
    "CS 331" : {
      "2014901001" : {
        "absence" : 0,
        "attendant" : 1
      }
    }
  },
  "instructor" : {
    "instructor01" : {
      "id" : "01"
    }
  },
  "instructorEnrollment" : {
    "01" : {
      "CS 331" : true
    }
  },
  "student" : {
    "student01" : {
      "id" : "2014901001",
      "name" : "Paul Howard"
    }
  },
  "studentEnrollment" : {
    "2014901001" : {
      "CS 331" : true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems that your data model will fulfill your needs! As you have done, you should not hesitate to duplicate data in NoSQL world. You may use a transaction to update the counters.

Comment: This is very tough to answer; when you say *improve it*, in what way do you want it improved? Is it not working for your use case? Can you describe the issue you're having with it? Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I would encourage you to provide some more details so we understand the scope of the question. Update the question and we'll take a look!

Answer (score 1):

This what i will design for such a user requirement

```
{
  "class_collection": {
    "documents": [
      {
        "id": "CS_331_2019_1",
        "type": "CS 331",
        "name": "Software Design",
        "enrolled_instructor": [
          "instructor_id_1"
        ],
        "enrolled_students": [
          {
            "id": "student_id_1",
            "absence": 0,
            "attendant": 2
          },
          {
            "id": "student_id_2",
            "absence": 2,
            "attendant": 3
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "class_attendance_collection": {
    "documents": [
      {
        "2019-03-12T18:00:00": {
          "class_id": "CS_331_2019_1",
          "attended": ["student_id_1"],
          "not_attended": ["student_id_2"]
        }
      },
      {
        "2019-03-13T16:00:00": {
          "class_id": "CS_331_2019_1",
          "attended": ["student_id_1","student_id_2"]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "student_collection": {
    "documents": [
      {
        "id": "student_id_1",
        "name": "name_1"
      },
      {
        "id": "student_id_2",
        "name": "name_2"
      }
    ]
  },
  "instructor_collection": {
    "documents": [
      {
        "id": "instructor_id_1",
        "name": "name_1"
      },
      {
        "id": "instructor_id_2",
        "name": "name_2"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Have fun coding :)

Comment: Great, but how I can retrieve classes which a specific student has enrolled in?

Comment: in mongoDB it will be something like this 
 db.class.find({"enrolled_students.id":"student_id_1"}  find out more https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/ in the no-sql world nested objects are called embedded

Comment: for firebase you should look at https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data got to "Filtering by a specified child key" section

Comment: Did you get the idea ?